# Qual a diferença entre uma DLL produzida com C++ e uma C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Após algum tempo pesquisando, não encontrei nenhum resultado para esta questão, os tópicos já existentes na MSDN também não retornaram nada em relação a suporte das 2 no Windows.

Em síntese, a dúvida é, qual a diferença após compilada de uma DLL produzida utilizando C++ e uma produzida com C#? Até onde consegui resultados, a do C++ parece rodar tranquilamente no Windows sem necessidade de instalações adicionais, já a do C# necessita sempre do .Net instalado. Esta afirmação está correta?

Além disso, é possível utilizar DLL's C# no C++ e vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua afirmação está parcialmente correta. Na verdade, as DLLs comuns (win32/Com) precisam ser registradas com a ferramenta `regsvr32` enquanto, de fato, você precisa apenas adicionar uma DLL C# na pasta `bin` para que a mesma possa ser utilizada (e ela só pode ser utilizada por aplicações .NET como você disse). Você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: [Difference between normal DLL and .Net DLL](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/dll.htm)

É possível utilizar uma DLL C++ em linguagens .NET. Para isso o Visual Studio cria um arquivo "interop" pra você. Basicamente um arquivo INTEROP é uma interface que permite que você acesse os recursos da DLL, ou seja, um `wrapper` para a DLL em que você utilizará os recursos da mesma sem se preocupar com qualquer conversão. Esse arquivo "interop" é criado porque as linguagens .NET precisam de descrição de tipo (apenas para serem "entendidos" pela linguagem). Você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: [What is the interop dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670940/what-is-the-interop-dll)

O contrário também é válido. Você pode usar uma DLL .NET em um programa C++. Para isso basta seguir este tutorial disponibilizado pela *Microsoft*: [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736)

Agora respondendo à questão fundamental. A diferença, após compiladas, entre uma DLL C++ e uma DLL C# é o formato. A DLL .NET é particionada em algumas seções:

- PE header
- CLR header
- CLR metadata
- CLR IL code
- Native data

Cada seção é interpretada pela linguagem .NET enquanto a DLL C++ não possui essas seções. Por isso mesmo, ela precisa de um `wrapper` como citei anteriormente. Essas seções são descritas aqui: [Inside .NET assemblies (part 1)](http://www.anotherchris.net/net/inside-net-assemblies-part-1/)