# C, C++, C#? Por qual delas um iniciante deve começar a aprender?

Tags: c#, c, c++

Tenho 17 anos e estou aprendendo Java, quando eu sentir que já domino a linguagem planejo migrar para .NET! Qual é o recomendado para começar C, C++ ou C#?
Obrigao pela ajuda ^^

Comment: Recomendo C++ pois tem tudo que C tem porém assim como java ela também é orientado a objetos, C++ pode ser complicado no começo, C# é orientado a objetos e é parecido com java, então acho que você vai se dar melhor com C# já que você quer aprender .NET também, mas isso é algo muito pessoal, vai de cada um

Comment: A pergunta é opinativa, por isso foi bem fechada, eu respondi em outra plataforma que permite este tipo de coisa: https://pt.quora.com/C-C-C-Por-qual-delas-um-iniciante-deve-come%C3%A7ar-a-aprender/answer/Antonio-Maniero

Answer (score 8):

Talvez essa pergunta seja fechada, por ser "*principalmente baseada em opiniões*", mas, creio que seja possível responde-la de forma objetiva.

---

> *C, C++, C#? Por qual delas um iniciante deve começar a aprender?*

Com certeza [C#](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp) é a "mais fácil" das três. **<sup>[1]</sup>**

C# tem uma sintaxe "mais intuitiva e menos exótica" (opinião), se comparada ao [C](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) e [C++](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), algumas pessoas inclusive consideram C e C++ como linguagens de **médio nível**, já que é possível escrever trechos usando a linguagem [Assembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/86952) nelas, que é de baixo nível. O nível de abstração no C# por outro lado é maior, se levarmos em consideração, por exemplo, que programas em C e C++ são compilados para linguagem de máquina e o C# é compilado para uma linguagem intermediária ([CIL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)), que depois é traduzida para código nativo ou executada por uma máquina virtual ([Is C# partially interpreted or really compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837367/8133067)).

O C# simplifica muitas tarefas, como **gerenciamento de memória** com o **Coletor de Lixo** (*Garbage Collector*), o que torna tudo muito mais simples. Em C e C++, um dos motivos do seu poder é que você controla tudo, incluindo alocação e liberação de memória, o que, por exemplo, pode aumentar muito o desempenho de uma aplicação, mas também tem um preço, porque a programação fica mais complexa e é mais fácil cometer falhas que acabem com vazamento de memória e problemas desse tipo.

Seguindo as datas de criação das linguagens, e dando alguns exemplos de níveis de abstração acrescentados de uma para outra, a lista ficaria nessa ordem:

1. **C** -> "*Criada em **1972** por Dennis Ritchie na empresa AT&T Bell Labs para desenvolvimento do sistema operacional Unix (originalmente escrito em Assembly).*" (da [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)))
2. **C++** -> "*Bjarne Stroustrup desenvolveu o C++ em **1983** no Bell Labs como um adicional à linguagem C.*" [da [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)) -> Abstração em relação ao C: Introduz a Programação Orientada a Objetos.
3. **C#** -> "*Durante o desenvolvimento da plataforma .NET, as bibliotecas foram escritas originalmente numa linguagem chamada Simple Managed C (SMC), que tinha um compilador próprio. Mas, em Janeiro de 1999, uma equipe de desenvolvimento foi formada por Anders Hejlsberg, que fora escolhido pela Microsoft para desenvolver a linguagem. Dá-se início à criação da linguagem chamada Cool. Um pouco mais tarde, em **2000**, o projeto .NET era apresentado ao público na Professional Developers Conference (PDC), e a linguagem Cool fora renomeada e apresentada como C#.*" (da [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp#Hist%C3%B3ria)) -> Abstração em relação ao C++: Introduz Coletor de Lixo, compilação para linguagem intermediária, etc.

---

> *Estou aprendendo Java, quando eu sentir que já domino a linguagem planejo migrar para .NET*

Se você está aprendendo Java, mais um motivo para começar pelo C#, já que as duas linguagens têm muitas similaridades. Na verdade, o C# foi meio que a resposta da Microsoft ao Java, veja esse artigo:

> [Por que a Microsoft criou o C#?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2018/03/02/why-did-microsoft-create-c/)
>
> [Resposta](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Microsoft-create-C-Wasnt-Java-good-enough-in-the-1990s/answer/Dan-Shappir-1) de Dan Shappir (trabalha no Wix), no Quora:
>
> Durante os anos 90, com Bill Gates no comando, e antes de Ballmer estragar tudo, a Microsoft estava no topo do monopólio do Windows. Foi alegado pelo Departamento de Defesa dos EUA que uma estratégia da Microsoft na época era "abraçar, estender e extinguir", significando que eles abraçariam uma tecnologia de sucesso, combinariam com o Windows e estenderiam para que ela se tornasse melhor, mas também incompatível com o original. Isso levaria os clientes a usar produtos Windows e Microsoft.
>
> Quando a Sun lançou o Java em 1995, a Microsoft percebeu o potencial da linguagem e do ecossistema e tentou implementar essa estratégia. Ela introduziu sua própria implementação da JVM com o IE3 e, em seguida, começou a aprimorá-la além do padrão Java. A Sun processou a Microsoft em outubro de 1997 por implementar de forma incompleta o padrão Java 1.1, o que forçou a Microsoft a descontinuar sua implementação.
>
> Em vez de migrar para a JVM da Sun e, assim, dar à Sun uma alavancagem significativa no mundo do Windows, a Microsoft decidiu “sair da Sun” pela Sun, introduzindo sua própria linguagem de programação e plataforma e efetivamente matando o Java no Windows. Eles trouxeram o renomado designer de linguagens de programação Anders Hejlsberg a bordo, que já tinha experiência em mudar e melhorar linguagens de programação existentes, e deram a ele a tarefa de criar um “Java melhor” (não oficialmente, mas na prática). Assim, o C# e o .NET Framework nasceram.

---

Mais informações sobre o assunto:

- [Por que escolher C ao invés de C++ ou então C++ no lugar de C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19073/86952)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma DLL produzida com C++ e uma C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98658/86952)
- [O que o C++ pode fazer que o C# não pode?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7740/86952)
- [Quais as diferenças mais relevantes entre C# e Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/86952)
- [Pode se usar C++ e C# usando programação C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169269/86952)
- [Quais os cenários em que o C# tem vantagem em relação a outras linguagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309322/86952)
- [List of C-family programming languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages)

---

**<sup>[1]</sup>** O Filipe colocou um bom ponto de vista no seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344020/#comment692842_344038):

> *É só uma opinião, como você mesmo disse é um post que vai de opinião a resposta, concordo que o C# seja a linguagem mais fácil, nos termos citados por você, mas caso a pessoa não saiba nada de programação, o paradigma Orientado a Objeto é mais complexo de se aprender para um iniciante, as vezes é melhor aprender um pouco de C pra entender conceitos e depois ir pra C#, porque se não a pessoa usa uma Linguagem de Paradigma Orientado a objeto e programa de forma estruturada*

Mas, no contexto da pergunta, em que o autor já está aprendendo Java (que é muito similar ao C# e também tem um paradigma de [POO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/86952)), e depois pretende migrar para .NET, creio que C# seja a escolha óbvia. Até porque eu não creio que exista hoje alguma forma de integração entre a linguagem C e o .NET: [How many languages does .NET framework support?](https://www.quora.com/How-many-languages-does-NET-framework-support).

Outras perguntas relacionadas a POO:

- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/86952)
- [Quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/86952)
- [POO é igual em todas as linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213951/86952)

Comment: É só uma opinião, como você mesmo disse é um post que vai de opinião a resposta, concordo que o C# seja a linguagem mais fácil, nos termos citados por você, mas caso a pessoa não saiba nada de programação, o paradigma Orientado a Objeto é mais complexo de se aprender para um iniciante, as vezes é melhor aprender um pouco de C pra entender conceitos e depois ir pra C#, porque se não a pessoa usa uma Linguagem de Paradigma Orientado a objeto e programa de forma estruturada

Comment: Verdade, bom ponto! Mas no contexto da pergunta, em que o autor já está aprendendo Java (que é muito similar ao C# e também tem um paradigma de POO), e depois pretende migrar para .NET, creio que C# seja a escolha óbvia. Até porque eu não creio que exista hoje alguma forma de integração entre a linguagem C e o .NET: [How many languages does .NET framework support?](https://www.quora.com/How-many-languages-does-NET-framework-support).

Comment: Sim no contexto e por ele estar já iniciando no Java o C# é o obviamente o mais indicado, até porque são muito parecidos, então migrar de um para o outro é tranquilo, ao dono da pergunta deixo a dica também, como esta iniciando a programar já em uma linguagem POO, tente aprender bem a respeito da Orientação a Objeto em si auxiliara mais ainda o aprendizado, visto que o uso de API's fará mais sentido, pois você entenderá o comportamento e funcionamento de maneira mais ampla

Comment: A resposta até é boa, bem trabalhada, o que eu acho que é um pouco complicado é que a pergunta não deixa de ser opiniativa e para isso existe o motivo de fechamento apropriado. Na verdade pode até ser fechada como fora de escopo porque dar opiniõa do que a pessoa deve aprender não está no nosso escopo. Especialmente em casos que sequer se conhece a realidade da pessoa. A resposta derrapa um pouco porque ela assume um lado e aí fica claramente opinativa. Apesar de eu concorda com ela, em parte, teria sido melhor se colocasse porque escolher cada uma deles, em vez de dizer qual delas escolher.

Comment: Parabéns pela dedicação, mas fica a dica do que pode melhorar e pras próximas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas @Maniero! Quando eu vi a pergunta logo pensei em sinaliza-la como "baseada em opiniões" sem dizer nada, mas lembrei que já encontrei perguntas no SOen um pouco parecidas com essa (apesar que essa está claramente pedindo uma opinião mesmo), mas que são dúvidas pertinentes e que acabam tendo respostas interessantes, que mostram vários pontos de vistas, comparando as linguagens e mostrando pontos de uma e outra. Nesse ponto, concordo totalmente que eu deveria ter tido um enfoque diferente e falado um pouco das características de cada uma!